# SQL Delete specific records with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below:

[image]

And the delete condition is:

delete from Employee only if the date is smaller than a specific date and no record is larger than that date

e.g.

- if the date is 3/8/2014, then only record with EmployeeID 3 will be removed as the record with EmployeeID 4 has date larger than 3/8/2014, and EmployeeID 5 won't be removed as the date is 3/9/2014
- if the date is 3/9/2014, then record with EmployeeID 3 and 5 will be removed, as the record with EmployeeID 4 has date larger than 3/9/2014

At first, I tried

```
delete from Employee where Date > @Date
```

But the above SQL would delete all records wherever the date is smaller than the @Date

What amendments should be made to the above SQL?

Comment: record 4 has a date less then 3/8/2014 i.e 3/7/2014 it will also be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE EmployeeID IN 
(SELECT EmployeeID FROM TableName
 GROUP BY EmployeeID
 HAVING MAX(DATE)<=@Date)
```

Tested and verified.

See an example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24dc09/3).

Comment: Remove the max(date) column from the Select in the in clause

Comment: @SoulTrain: Removed. Thanks, mate. Now tested and verified.

Comment: mate you should have <= instead of only <. It makes difference for case 2 that user has given.

Comment: @AK47 the users conditions 1 and 2 contradict with each other.

Comment: @damien, how? can you please explain?

Comment: @AK47 yes I understand it somewhat now. It means that delete only records whome date is less then the provided date, if any less date is found with the current date and its id, don't delete it.

Comment: Delete only those ID's who don't have any Date (not a single record) greater than this Date. All the records of particular ID should be equal or less that Date which is passed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
delete from Employee
where EmployeeID in
(select EmployeeID 
from Employee
group by Employeeid
having max(Date) < @Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is,

```
Declare @d date ='3/8/2014'


delete from myEmp where empID in
(
select empID from myEmp
group by empID
having MAX(empDate) <=@d
)
```

Link for Demo,
[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f697a/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
create table #t (EmployeeID int, Date datetime)

insert #t values 
(3, '20140304'),
(3, '20140305'),
(3, '20140306'),
(4, '20140307'),
(4, '20140308'),
(4, '20140310'),
(5, '20140309')

declare @date date = '20140308'

;with x as (
    select t.*
    from #t t
    where Date <= @date and not exists (
    select * from #t t2 where t.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeID and Date > @date)
)
delete x;
```